# How to fill in the new created column efficiently?

Tags: sql-server

I Have a table below and I will create a new column say named 'Amount'. The existing column 'Id' is foreign key and link the information in a table say 'Loan'('Id' is the primary key of table 'Loan' ). The simple thing I wanna do is assign each new created Amount cell with the right amount obtain from table 'Loan', mapping with 'Id'. I currently use local variable and self-created table type to find the amount value in 'Loan' case by case. Is there any other more efficient way to execute the same operation? Many thanks.
MyTable was as below:

[image]

My code was as followed:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD Amount  MONEY


CREATE TYPE ListofID AS TABLE (idx INT IDENTITY(1,1), ID VARCHAR(255))

DECLARE @Table_ID_List  ListofID
INSERT @Table_ID_List  (
ID )
SELECT Id FROM MyTable

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @cnt INT
SELECT @i = min(idx) - 1, @cnt = max(idx) FROM @Table_ID_List  

DECLARE @app VARCHAR(255)

WHILE @i<@cnt

BEGIN

     SELECT @i = @i + 1
     SELECT @app = (SELECT ID FROM @Table_ID_List  WHERE idx = @i)

     UPDATE MyTable
     SET Amount =(SELECT Amount FROM Loan  WHERE Id =  @app)

     WHERE Id =  @app

END
```

Comment: You can assign a scalar function to the default. You can't pass it any column values.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You'll need to tell is what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have missed your question, but I believe you can do this directly via an Update statement. Something along the lines of:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD Amount MONEY


UPDATE 
   t1 
SET
   t1.Amount = t2.Amount 
FROM
    MyTable t1
    JOIN Loan t2 
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Wouldn't that do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your table, you may want to use the SWITCH statement to transfer the whole table at once to the new schema.

https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo